# arm: ./busybox: line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")

Tags: build, arm, cross-compiling, busybox, armv7

I am setting up a virtual machine specifically for crosscompiling for armv7l. As a test I decided to compile busybox, and while the crosscompilation itself works fine, upon uploading the resulting binary to a router with the correct architecture, the binary complains about `./busybox: line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")`

I did not have this issue when compiling for x86, and as such I believe the problem is with my build environment.

It's based on ubuntu18 server, and I've installed these packages:

```
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi
libncurses5-dev
gawk
build-essentials
make
```

my buildscript:

```
export ac_cv_linux_vers=2
export CC=/usr/local/arm-2011.09/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export GCC=/usr/local/arm-2011.09/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
export CXX=/usr/local/arm-2011.09/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
export CPP=/usr/local/arm-2011.09/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-cpp
export LD=/usr/local/arm-2011.09/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld
export AR=/usr/local/arm-2011.09/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ar
export AS=/usr/local/arm-2011.09/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-as
export NM=/usr/local/arm-2011.09/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-nm
export RANLIB=/usr/local/arm-2011.09/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/bin/ranlib
export CC1=/usr/local/arm-2011.09/libexec/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1/cc1
export PATH=/usr/local/arm-2011.09/bin:/usr/local/arm-2011.09/:/usr/local/arm-2011.09/lib:/usr/local/arm-2011.09/libexec/gcc/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/4.6.1:$PATH
export ac_cv_func_getpgrp_void=yes
export ac_cv_func_setpgrp_void=yes
export LDFLAGS="-static"
export CFLAGS="-Os -s"
# I already did make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi- 
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
make install
```

Any obvious flaws with my build process?

---

The platform on which I am trying to run busybox:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 1594.16
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult edsp thumbee tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x4
CPU part    : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 1
CPU physical    :0

processor   : 1
model name  : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
BogoMIPS    : 1594.16
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult edsp thumbee tls 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant : 0x4
CPU part    : 0xc09
CPU revision    : 1
CPU physical    :1

Hardware    : Hisilicon A9
Revision    : 0000
Serial      : 0000000000000000

# uname -m
armv7l
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It turned out that my `make menuconfig` was incomplete.

```
Busybox Settings -> Build Options -> Build Busybox as a static binary (no shared libs)
Busybox Settings -> Build Options -> Cross compiler prefix -> Set this option equal to "arm-linux-gnueabi-"
Busybox Settings -> Installation Options -> Don't use /usr -> Enable
Linux Module Utilities -> () Default directory containing modules -> blank
```

after that, the binary produced by the build script worked as intended